# Handling Host Listener and third party libraries in Angular universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I am implementing angular universal and successfully created
**dist/server.js**.

**package.json**

```
{
      "name": "website",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
        "serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
        "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run website:server",
        "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
        "start:express": "node_modules/ts-node ./server.ts"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
        "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
        "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-server": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
        "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^8.1.1",
        "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.1.1",
        "angular-carousel": "^1.1.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "class-transformer": "^0.2.0",
        "color-thief": "^2.2.5",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
        "ng5-slider": "^1.1.14",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
        "ngx-loading": "^3.0.1",
        "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
        "ts-loader": "^6.1.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.8",
        "@angular/cli": "~7.0.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.14",
        "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.2",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "^4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~3.1.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.8"
      }
    }
```

**server.ts**

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');

// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// TODO: implement data requests securely
app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
});

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

I have used [OwldatePicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime) library which uses events.

Error i get

[image]

I tried to use global['Event'] as per [this](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/844#issuecomment-346929471).

1. How this can be solved if one is using third party libraries and want to achieve SSR for SEO.
2. What is standard way of handling events for implementing Angular universal?

Comment: There is an issue open for that: https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker/issues/552